# xvimagesink not found by gst-inspect

Tags: windows, gstreamer

I have installed GStreamer SDK (x64) and GStreamer SDK (Development Files) (x64) on a Windows 7 PC.  This was a complete install - all features were enabled.
When I run **gst-inspect-0.10 xvimagesink** the result is **No such element or plug-in 'xvimagesink'**
Running gst-inspect on other basic plug-ins returns the expected information.  Is this plug-in not supported under Windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**xvimagesink** uses the xwindow system of linux and is hence not supported on windows.

Use **autovideosink** instead. It will auto-plug an appropriate sink element.

Comment: To be more specific, you can use `osxvideosink`. Reference: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+16%3A+Platform-specific+elements

Comment: I am using linux arm64 arch. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: autovideosink doesnt display anything